# Android multitouch glitches

Tags: android, multi-touch

I've just made a quick system that has two joysticks (one for movement, one for shooting) and they work with multitouch.

However, when you use both at the same time they interfere with each other (You slow down, turn weirdly, etc) and am wondering whether this is an issue with my phone (Nexus One, 2.3.6) or an issue with the code:

```
public void handleEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    switch(action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            pointerID = event.getPointerId(0);
            int tx = (int) event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(pointerID));
            int ty = (int) event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(pointerID));
            boolean reset = true;
            if(tx >= (x - radius * 2) && (tx <= (x + radius * 2))) {
                if(ty >= (y - radius * 2) && (ty <= (y + radius * 2))) {
                    dx = (tx - x);
                    dy = (ty - y);
                    reset = false;
                }
            }
            if(reset) pointerID = -1;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            if(pointerID == -1) {
                final int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                pointerID = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                int tx = (int) event.getX(pointerIndex);
                int ty = (int) event.getY(pointerIndex);
                if(tx >= (x - radius * 2) && (tx <= (x + radius * 2))) {
                    if(ty >= (y - radius * 2) && (ty <= (y + radius * 2))) {
                        dx = (tx - x);
                        dy = (ty - y);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if(pointerID != -1) {
                final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerID);
                int tx = (int) event.getX(pointerIndex);
                int ty = (int) event.getY(pointerIndex);
                if(tx >= (x - radius * 2) && (tx <= (x + radius * 2))) {
                    if(ty >= (y - radius * 2) && (ty <= (y + radius * 2))) {
                        dx = (tx - x);
                        dy = (ty - y);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            final int id = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if(id == pointerID) {
                dy = 0;
                dx = 0;
                pointerID = -1;
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            if(-1 != pointerID) {
                dy = 0;
                dx = 0;
                pointerID = -1;
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Important notes:

Each joystick is a class, and the handleEvent method is called for each joystick.

`pointerID` is an int belonging to each joystick

`dy` and `dx` are just the distance from the center of the joystick.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that if there are multiple touches happening at the same time, that one MotionEvent contains them all (and if one of the touches is of the type ACTION_MOVE, it also contains a history of that movement).

Use a loop over event.getPointerCount() (if it is >1) as indexes to get ID's for each touchpoint, which you can then use to track the touch and get the touch's x/y/other information.

Now the thing to realise is that the pointerID not only tracks the touch ... but it also can change if a touch point goes away (finishing with an ACTION_UP event); a POINTER_DOWN event will always add that touch with an ID at the end (so if you have two touches it will get the ID 2), but on a POINTER_UP (or POINTER_2_UP if it''s the second touch point), the points with a higher ID change ID by moving down.

So if you have touches with ID 0, 1 and 2, and the second touch (ID 1) goes POINTER_UP, you have to realise that pointerID 2 will change into ID 1.  And if you have two touches (0 and 1), if ID 0 goes up, all of the sudden ID 1 becomes ID 0!

The trick is to keep track of this with some global variables (leftJoyStickID and rightJoyStickID) and some code in action_down and action_up. With just two touchpoints, the ternary operator is your friend:

if (IDofActionUpEvent == leftJoyStickID)
{
rightJoyStickID = IDofActionUpEvent == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

Comment: I don't know if you realise, but each item that needs to be multi-touched is a class, and so the `ACTION_MOVE` is called for each joystick, and will only run on the one with the correct pointer ID. I have run this (possibly slightly adjusted..) code on my new phone and tablet and it works fine; i.e: the multitouch on my Nexus One was at fault at least partially.